# Why does adding reloadData in the willDisplay cell prevent cell dequeuing on scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So I am making a kind of timeline where every day is represented by 1 cell in a really wide horizontal collectionView. Here you can see/try the full code  https://github.com/AlexMarshall12/singleDayTimeline.git. Its also copied below

```
    let cellIdentifier = "DayCollectionViewCell"
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    var dates = [Date?]()
    var startDate: Date?
    var endDate: Date?
    private var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

    @IBOutlet weak var daysCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        daysCollectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "DayCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

        let allDates = Helper.generateRandomDate(daysBack: 900, numberOf: 10)
        self.dates = allDates.sorted(by: {
            $0!.compare($1!) == .orderedAscending
        })
        self.startDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: dates.first as! Date)

        self.endDate = dates.last!
        self.dates = Array(dates.suffix(from: 8))
        print(self.dates)
        daysCollectionView.delegate = self
        daysCollectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    var onceOnly = false
    internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if !onceOnly {
            //let lastDateIndexPath = IndexPath(row: dates.count - 1,section: 0)
            let lastDate = dates.last
            let lastDayIndex = lastDate!?.interval(ofComponent: .day, fromDate: startDate!)
            let lastDayCellIndexPath = IndexPath(row: lastDayIndex!, section: 0)
            self.daysCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: lastDayCellIndexPath, at: .left, animated: false)
            self.selectedIndexPath = lastDayCellIndexPath
            self.daysCollectionView.reloadData() //LINE IN QUESTION
            onceOnly = true
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let days = self.endDate!.days(from: self.startDate!)
        if days <= 150 {
            return 150
        } else {
            print(days,"days")
            return days + 1
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = daysCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DayCollectionViewCell

        let cellDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: indexPath.item, to: self.startDate!)

        if let selectedRow = selectedIndexPath {
            cell.reloadCell(selectedRow==indexPath)
        } else {
            cell.reloadCell(false)
        }

        if Calendar.current.component(.day, from: cellDate!) == 15 {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM"
            let monthString = dateFormatter.string(from: cellDate!)
            cell.drawMonth(month: monthString)
        }
        if Calendar.current.component(.day, from: cellDate!) == 1 && Calendar.current.component(.month, from: cellDate!) == 1 {
            print("drawYEAR")
            cell.drawYear(year:Calendar.current.component(.year, from: cellDate!))
        }
        if self.dates.contains(where: { Calendar.current.isDate(cellDate!, inSameDayAs: $0!) }) {
            print("same")
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.dates.count)))
        let randomDate = self.dates[randomIndex]
        let daysFrom = randomDate?.days(from: self.startDate!)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: daysFrom!, section: 0)
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

        //daysCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
        daysCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        daysCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

So there are 2 randomly generated dates at the tail end of 900 days prior to the current date. In the very beginning I use the willDisplay cell callback to scroll to the very last date (the most recent) which happens to be the last cell in entire collectionView. Then at the very end of that function I do daysCollectionView.reloadData(). When this happens, no matter where you scroll, the collectionView stops dequeuing cells, cellForItemAt is never called again.

Notably you can tell because only that original far right block of the entire View is colored blue, if you scroll to the left, its just clear because nothing is coloring the cells anymore. Why would this reloadData function stop this process?

Comment: Just a guess, but I think it's by design. Similar to a table view, cells are *expensive* items to create and set up - thus, if you are displaying 10, you may only have 12-15 in memory... to save on scrolling and memory, even if your data source has 10,000 items. With this sort of design, why would you wish to call `reloadData` like this? You might as well code you way into a recursive call - and risk freezing everything.

Comment: `reloadData` is a big hammer.  It basically tells the collection view that the entire data source has changed and it really needs to throw everything away and start again with regard to layout.  I wouldn't use a collection view for this.  I would just use paging in a scrollview and manipulate the scroll offset to give the appearance of an endless set of items